# How do you use ffmpeg to change video saturation over time?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -vf eq=brightness=0.1:saturation=0.5*t:1:0.5*t -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Use the parameter `t`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change to per-frame evaluation mode,

```
eq=eval=frame:brightness=...
```